# Col variable not defined in stats summary loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, summary

I have been struggling with a loop to create a stats summary for each column in my dataframe (df3). The loop ideally is to append each columns summary data as a column in a new dataframe. Here is a sample of my data:

```
          DJI Price Open     Close      High       Low  Difference  \
Date                                                                 
1/2/2020        28638.97  28868.80  28872.80  28627.77      245.03   
1/3/2020        28553.33  28634.88  28716.31  28500.36      215.95   
1/6/2020        28465.50  28703.38  28708.02  28418.63      289.39   
1/7/2020        28639.18  28583.68  28685.50  28565.28      120.22   
1/8/2020        28556.14  28745.09  28866.18  28522.51      343.67   
         Price Difference   Price Range   Y/N Event?  Volume  AHT Loss?  
Date                                                                   
1/2/2020         49.9424          Low           1  2.5182          1  
1/3/2020         44.0153          Low           0  2.3959          1  
1/6/2020         58.9834          Low           0  2.5276          1  
1/7/2020         24.5034          Low           1  2.5890          1  
1/8/2020         70.0470       Medium           0  2.9175          0
```

And here is my broken loop. I'm not sure how/ if I can define col as a variable representing each dataframe column and to then test if that col is a column to summarize and append to the end of the new df: Sumry

```
# Summary loops
colheads = df3.columns
col = colheads.columns
Sumry = []
for col in colheads:
    Sumry.append(df3.query('col == True')['summary'].mean())
return
```

Comment: Just `df3.describe(include='all')` doesn't work for you? I would be helpful if you provide an expected output for your example.

Comment: Anyways, `col = colheads.columns` should fails because "'Index' object has no attribute 'columns'" and this `df3.query('col == True')` should be replaced to `df.query(f'{col} == True')` in order to work.